# Check reachability for internet access proxy

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, reachability

I have read number of questions related with Reachability but i have new case can summarized below :-

1. I have connect to WiFi-network.
2. This network need access Username & Password to access internet such as cafes .
3. I try used Reachability & NSURLConnection but i didn't find any criteria to identifify if i reach to any domain (http://www.google.com) or if i reach to internet access login to enter my credantional information to be able to use internet service.

Comment: When your device attempted to connect to those WIFI network, should you already be prompted for user name and password?

Comment: I know but what about handling ,or how i can know this case happen to tell user about this case

Comment: 1.  Check Reachability for WIFI. If fails, notifying user as such.  End.  2. If step 1 is ok,  check Reachability for Internet.  If it fails, suggest users that they 2 probable causes: a. No internet. B.  they are using proxy server that required user id and password.

Comment: Some answers to this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306658/ios-reachability-fails-to-catch-the-case-where-connected-to-wifi-but-not-logged