# main thread blockage is causing app to crash in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, reachability

My app crashes on startup because with exception 'failed to scene-update in time'

this is because reachability does not return on time 
Here is the stack trace

```
com.tjango.Plus3 failed to scene-update in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 2.590 (user 2.590, system 0.000), 12% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.302, 1% CPU


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
_semaphore_wait_trap + 8
__dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 252
_xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 184
___SCNetworkReachabilityServer_targetStatus + 192
___SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags + 440
_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags + 232
-[Reachability currentReachabilityStatus] Reachability.m:295
```

this happens on iOS 8 only.

The function where it gets stuck is Apple's Reachability library :
I can't figure out why would this function block it.

```
- (NetworkStatus)currentReachabilityStatus

{

    NSAssert(_reachabilityRef != NULL, @"currentNetworkStatus called with NULL SCNetworkReachabilityRef");

    NetworkStatus returnValue = NotReachable;

    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;



    if (SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(_reachabilityRef, &flags))

    {

        if (_alwaysReturnLocalWiFiStatus)

        {

            returnValue = [self localWiFiStatusForFlags:flags];

        }

        else

        {

            returnValue = [self networkStatusForFlags:flags];

        }

    }



    return returnValue;

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337416/ios-8-0-failed-to-scene-update-in-time-crash)? Basically, the question is: do you have any expensive processes running on the main thread? In your case, at the start-up of your app. If you do, please share the code for it. Making it asynchronous will probably fix your problem.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should never do anything on the main thread that takes more than about a quarter of a second. Any such operation must be done on a background thread (preferably with using `dispatch_async()` or `NSOperationQueue`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reachability is probably the single most incorrectly used library on iOS. These rules help:

1. Reachability should not be called on the main thread. Call it on a secondary thread and have that thread notify the main thread of network changes.
2. Do not check network status before attempting a connection - just try the connection and handle errors as needed. There are times when the network will be offline to save power until someone tries a connection.
3. Reachability is mostly useful for detecting when the network comes back online after being offline. You can retry failed connections at that point.

See my comment: [iOS Reachability fails to catch the case where connected to WiFi but not logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306658/ios-reachability-fails-to-catch-the-case-where-connected-to-wifi-but-not-logged/15306728#15306728)